# How to sort a List[HashMap[String, Any]] with dynamic fields

Tags: scala, list, sorting, hashmap

The following function takes in keys and the events to sort.  Keys can be a maximum of size 4, for now.

```
def sortNow(keys: List[(String, String), events:List[java.util.HashMap[String, Any]]): Any = {
   keys.length match {
  case 1 => events.sortBy(event => {
    val values = getValues(keys, event)
    values match {
      case List(a: String) => a.asInstanceOf[String]
    }
  })
  case 2 => events.sortBy(event => {
    val values = getValues(keys, event)
    values match {
      case List(a, b) => (a.asInstanceOf[String], b.asInstanceOf[String])
    }
  })
  case 3 => events.sortBy(event => {
    val values = getValues(keys, event)
    values match {
      case List(a, b, c) => (a.asInstanceOf[String], b.asInstanceOf[String], c.asInstanceOf[String])
    }
  })(Ordering[(String, String, String)].reverse)
  case 4 => events.sortBy(event => {
    val values = getValues(keys, event)
    values match {
      case List(a, b, c, d) => (a.asInstanceOf[String], b.asInstanceOf[String], c.asInstanceOf[String], d.asInstanceOf[String])
    }
  })
  case default => throw new NotImplementedException
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the data and desired output then it would be good to understand the problem and your solution